# Remove trailing slash from url with blogger

Tags: redirect, blogger

My problem is that I am getting a lot of 404 errors for my blogger blog. These errors are coming on the posts which are available on my blog but the other person is obliged to access them with a trailing slash in the end which causes a 404 error.
For Example,

http://www.helpitx.com/2014/10/how-to-keep-your-online-information.html/ (It gives a 404 error)
http://www.helpitx.com/2014/10/how-to-keep-your-online-information.html (It opens actual webpage)

Now the question arises, is there any method to redirect all urls with trailing slash to original URL without trailing slash in blogger?
As we all know that blogger doesn't have any option of .htaccess so we cannot use this type of redirection.
The other method is using custom redirection but I am afraid of using this method because it may cause error of too many redirects.
Is there any simple method to redirect all trailing slash urls to original URL?

Comment: **blogger doesn't have any option of .htaccess** Can you clarify this?

Comment: @anubhava blogger doesn't support for .htacess, it's only support for custom redirection for specified URL

Comment: oh ok got it, I will stay away from this question then, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following Javascript snippet in the head region of your blog (preferable just below `<head>` tag in **Template > Edit HTML** )

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "error_page"'>
<script>
if( window.location.pathname.slice(-1) == "/" ) {
window.location.href = window.location.href.slice(0,window.location.href.length-1) 
}
</script>
</b:if>
```

It checks the URL and if it finds that there is a trailing slash at the end of the URL , then it opens the specific URL again without the trailing slash. This kind of redirection is best done at the server side but as Blogger doesn't provide full access to its backend , then this is the second best way (better way would be setting up 301 redirects from the **Settings > Search preferences > Errors and redirections** option but as you have already ruled it out due to requirement of manually entering each URL , I wouldn't stress it but that is best way to do this )

Comment: When I added this comment inside <head> tag, it was redirecting all pages which was looking critical for bots to crawl my page. At that time I was using page speed insights which was also giving redirection errors. Then I just added this code inside conditional tag for error page and every thing is working fine.

Comment: @JariUllah enclosing it inside b:if conditional tag for error page is a good idea , have changed the above code accordingly